# Slow loading UiTableView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have problem with Loading on UiTableView i have delay 4 sec on 4s iphone and 9sec 4 iphone. I use Async to download image and is very fast.

```
 -(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"item2";
    NSLog(@"loading");
    MenuCell *cells = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"1");
    cells.Title.text=[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cells.Title setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(red/255.f) green:(green/255.f) blue:(blue/255.f) alpha:1.0f]];
    NSLog(@"2");

   NSLog(@"3");
   [cells.Image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[page_icon objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clickgatemikro.png"]];
    NSLog(@"4");
   return cells;
}
```

And my output: (4sec Delay) :

```
2014-10-17 17:28:19.504 Accounting[501:53015]   numberOfRowsInSection  TABLE COUNT  : 12
2014-10-17 17:28:19.513 Accounting[501:53015]   numberOfRowsInSection  TABLE COUNT  : 12
2014-10-17 17:28:19.515 Accounting[501:53015] loading
2014-10-17 17:28:23.609 Accounting[501:53015] 1
2014-10-17 17:28:23.611 Accounting[501:53015] 2
2014-10-17 17:28:23.612 Accounting[501:53015] 3
2014-10-17 17:28:23.624 Accounting[501:53015] 4
2014-10-17 17:28:23.625 Accounting[501:53015] loading
2014-10-17 17:28:23.635 Accounting[501:53015] 1
2014-10-17 17:28:23.635 Accounting[501:53015] 2
2014-10-17 17:28:23.636 Accounting[501:53015] 3
2014-10-17 17:28:23.638 Accounting[501:53015] 4
2014-10-17 17:28:23.639 Accounting[501:53015] loading
2014-10-17 17:28:23.645 Accounting[501:53015] 1
2014-10-17 17:28:23.651 Accounting[501:53015] 2
2014-10-17 17:28:23.652 Accounting[501:53015] 3
2014-10-17 17:28:23.654 Accounting[501:53015] 4
2014-10-17 17:28:23.698 Accounting[501:53015] FINISH
```

----------Update-------------

Here is my code i use plist to load my datas on my Mutablearray and then i call reloadData

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self initVariables];
[self initplist];
self.mytableview.delegate = self;
self.mytableview.dataSource = self;

name = [plistDict objectForKey:@"title"];
image= [plistDict objectForKey:@"image"];


[self.mytableview reloadData];

}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
NSLog(@"  numberOfRowsInSection  TABLE COUNT  : %lu",(unsigned long)[name count]);
return [name count];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1; 
}
```

Comment: Is this problem happening after a call to `reloadData`? Show where you call `reloadData`. Make sure it's done on the main thread. There's nothing wrong with your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

When you want display images from an URL, use Async, because it's blocking the page drawing in sync mode, use a placeholder during the image dl and replace the placeholder with the image.

Comment: The OP is using async loading of images. Notice the log output. The cell loading is really fast.

Comment: 2014-10-17 17:28:19.515  loading ->
2014-10-17 17:28:23.609  1    (4 sec delay) the problem is on inititalize i think

Comment: @Cliff I just noticed that. It seems that the first need to load the cell from the xib or storyboard is causing a huge delay.

Comment: You mean tha is wrong to load external cell? Like uitablecell?

Comment: @Cliff No, it's not wrong. Lots of people do it. I'm simply pointing out a possible cause. I do everything in code so I'm not sure what would cause such a long delay with using a cell from a xib or storyboard.

Comment: If i rerurn 0 on method numberofrowsinselection it runs very fast. But if i return 1 i have delay again